# Trying to replace Fragment but it keeps on showing the same Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two Fragments. For examples like Fragment A and Fragment B, As the Activity starts, Fragment A is started. Now I enter some input which should start Fragment B, it reaches in Fragment B(executes its code) but it keeps on showing Fragment A.
What could possibly be going wrong ? Any help would be appreciated.

```
    homeScreenFragment = new HomeScreenFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.home_layout, homeScreenFragment, "Home Page").
            addToBackStack("Main Home Page").commit();
```

I run this fragment in MainActivity Class, Now after entering some text in Searchview, a AsyncTask gets executed and on its completion I try to run another Fragment (as shown in the code).

```
    public void SearchMovieTaskComplete(MovieDetails[] details) {
    if(details!=null){
        SearchResultFragment searchResultFragment= new SearchResultFragment();
        Bundle data=new Bundle();
        data.putSerializable("MovieDetail",details);
        searchResultFragment.setArguments(data);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.home_layout,searchResultFragment,"searchedResultCollected").commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code where u wrote logic to show fragment B

Comment: I have added some code snippets, please have a look at it.

Comment: Did you check if it's called with `details` set to `null`?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are adding a fragment everytime you do that (for what I understood in your code). So basically what you have to do is to keep a `FragmentA` object and a `FragmentB` object in your `Activity`. Then based on that you replace instead of adding. When you add they will just overlap. Do this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.home_layout, homeScreenFragment, "Home Page").addToBackStack("Main Home Page").commit();
```

d